# Can't add git alias when using shell function

Tags: git, git-bash, git-alias

I'm trying to add the following alias using shell function

```
scommit = "!f() { git submodule foreach -q --recursive 'git commit -a || :' ; git commit -am \" Update submodule \";}; f"
```

But when I run it in Git bash (on Windows)

```
git config --local alias.scommit "!f() { git submodule foreach -q --recursive 'git commit -a || :' ; git commit -am "" Update submodule "";}; f"
```

I got output

```
git config --local alias.scommit "fit fetch upstream() { git submodule foreach -q --recursive 'git commit -a || :' ; git commit -am "" Update submodule "";}; f"
```

and of course it doesn't work because

> Expansion of alias 'scommit' failed; 'fit' is not a git command

Also I tried to run it in PowerShell but it shows usage: git config [] …

When I add it to .git/config manually then it works.

How can I add this alias using git bash/ command line / PowerShell ? 
Why does it transforms to `fit fetch upstream()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested, on Windows 10, with Git 2.18:

```
git config --local alias.scommit '!f() { git submodule foreach -q --recursive "git commit -a" || : ; git commit -am "Update submodule";}; f'
```

The idea is to inverse the quotes: [strong quotes](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html#uh-1) (`'`) at the outside of the alias, [weak quotes](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html#uh-1) (`"`) inside.

That avoids for `!` to be interpreted as extended a command from history (as you [can see here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/355773/7490)) (although `set +o histexpand` before the git config command could have helped)